# Angular2 *.ngIf not working after first click

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular2 Framework so excuse any common mistakes. I have two forms in 2 div tags. One is login form another is a password reset form. Under the login form  there is a link that when clicked hides the login form on displays the password reset form.

Under the password reset form there is link that when clicked on hides the password reset form and shows the login form.

By default the login form is visible. Here is the HTML code

```
 <div class="login-block" *ngIf="!showResetPassword">                 
                <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <div>
                    <label for="username"></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="username"  id="username" formControlName="username" />
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label for="password"></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"  id="password" formControlName="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" >Log In</button>
                </div>
                </form> 
                    <div>
                        <a  href="#"  (click)="onTogglePasswordReset($event)" >Reset Password?</a>  
                </div>             
        </div> 
            <div class="login-block"  *ngIf="showResetPassword">
              <form [formGroup]="resetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(resetForm)">
                  <h1>Reset password</h1>
                 <div>
                     <label for="resetusername"></label>
                     <input type="text" placeholder="username"  id="resetusername" formControlName="resetusername" />
                </div>
                <div>
                 <button type="submit">Continue</button>
                </div>
               </form>
                <div>
                <a  href="#"  (click)="onTogglePasswordReset($event)">Account Access</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is my typescript function

```
onTogglePasswordReset (e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();
      this.showResetPassword=!this.showResetPassword; 
      alert(this.showResetPassword);
  }
```

The problem I am having is that when I go in for the first time and click on 'Reset Password' link, the reset form is shown fine but when I click on 'Account Access' it does not show the login form. so it works once and then stops.

The weird part is that if I display the Password Reset form on Startup and then click on on 'Account Access' it does show the login form. If I thenclick on 'Reset Password' link, the reset form is shown fine but when I click on 'Account Access' again it does not show the login form. so it works twiceand then stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, since you did not provide your complete component code, that you forgot to define your `FormControl`s and `FormGroup`s in your `component.ts`
When testing on Plunker the console displayed the following error :

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one
>   in.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
>
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
> ```

Adding the FormControls solved the problem

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm = new FormGroup({username: new FormControl(), password: new FormControl()})
  resetForm = new FormGroup({resetusername: new FormControl()})
  showResetPassword = false;

  constructor() { 

  }

  onTogglePasswordReset () {
      this.showResetPassword = !this.showResetPassword; 
  }

}
```

**[Here is the code on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iSHyGjMwFDK7zcrWLbSt?p=preview)** if you wish to try it for yourself.

Comment: I had the form Conrtols declared in the ts file, just didnt paste them. Your code in plunker is working finr but I still get have the same issue on my end.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to narrow down the error using your Plunker code. The second form had an input control that wasn't referenced correctly in the form builder code in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

use this one

in your template

```
<a (click)="toggle(false)" *ngIf="showResetPass">Reset Password</a>
<a (click)="toggle(true)" *ngIf="!showResetPass">Access Account</a>
```

inside your component

```
private resetPassVisible = false;

toggle(bool) {
    this.resetPassVisible = bool;
}
```